# Input array object in textBox WindowsForm

Tags: arrays, powershell, winforms, input, textbox

I try to input array object *$WinRoles* (Get-WindowsFeature from remote hosts). Need to insert *$WinRoles.DisplayName* and *$WinRoles.InstallState* as a table in textbox *$TextBoxInstalledRolesFeatures*

My Code (**This is the part of code where this problem occurs**) below. Where i missing?

```
    <#------======== Label Installed Roles&Features ========------#>
$LabelInstalledRolesFeatures = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$LabelInstalledRolesFeatures.Location = '810,10'
$LabelInstalledRolesFeatures.AutoSize = $true
$LabelInstalledRolesFeatures.Text = 'Installed Roles and Features'
$CommonForm.Controls.Add($LabelInstalledRolesFeatures)
<#------======== Label Installed Roles&Features ========------#>
<#------======== TextBox Installed Roles&Features ========------#>
$TextBoxInstalledRolesFeatures = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$TextBoxInstalledRolesFeatures.Location = '810,30'
$TextBoxInstalledRolesFeatures.Size = '250,316'
$TextBoxInstalledRolesFeatures.Text = ''
$CommonForm.Controls.Add($TextBoxInstalledRolesFeatures)
<#------======== TextBox Installed Roles&Features ========------#>
<#------======== Button Show Roles&Features ========------#>
$ButtonShowRolesFeatures = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$ButtonShowRolesFeatures.Location = '985, 5'
$ButtonShowRolesFeatures.Text = 'Show'
$ButtonShowRolesFeatures.AutoSize = $true
$ButtonShowRolesFeatures.add_Click({


        $SelectedServer = $ListboxListeServers.SelectedItem
        $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $SelectedServer
        $WinRoles = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
                        Get-WindowsFeature | where Installed -eq $true
                    }
        [array]$AllRoles = $WinRoles | select DisplayName, InstallState
        $TextBoxInstalledRolesFeatures.Text = $AllRoles
})
$CommonForm.Controls.Add($ButtonShowRolesFeatures)
<#------======== Button Show Roles&Features ========------#>
```

Comment: `$WinRoles.GetType() =` and trying to assign an object to a textbox will result in its stringification

Comment: Sounds like you'll want to [use a `DataGrid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-add-tables-and-columns-to-the-windows-forms-datagrid-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) rather than a `ListBox`

Comment: Oh sorry, $WinRoles.GetType() - i just look what the type this variable And forgot to remove ".GetType()". Now i fixed it in part of my code.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, may be it is that what i need. If it is not problem for you, can you show me example to use DataGrid in my code?

Comment: `$TextBoxInstalledRolesFeatures.Text = $AllRoles` should be `$TextBoxInstalledRolesFeatures.Items.AddRange($AllRoles)` thats the main problem but I agree with Mathias you should use a DGV for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [`DataGridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) instead of a `ListBox` as [Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) recommended in comments. The implementation is not very complex and is the ideal control for your use case. I don't have `Get-WindowsFeature` in my laptop but as an example, here is an implementation using `Get-Process` as the grid's data source:

```bash
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$CommonForm = [System.Windows.Forms.Form]@{
    Size          = '1800, 900'
    StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
}

$ListboxListeServers = [System.Windows.Forms.ListBox]@{
    Location = '30, 40'
    Size     = '200, 800'
}
$ListboxListeServers.Items.AddRange(@((Get-Process).ProcessName | Sort-Object -Unique))
$CommonForm.Controls.Add($ListboxListeServers)

$dgvInstalledRolesFeatures = [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView]@{
    Location = '240, 40'
    Size     = '1400, 800'
}
$CommonForm.Controls.Add($dgvInstalledRolesFeatures)

$ButtonShowRolesFeatures = [System.Windows.Forms.Button]@{
    Location = '985, 5'
    Text     = 'Show'
    AutoSize = $true
}

$processlist = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$ButtonShowRolesFeatures.add_Click({
    $processlist.AddRange(@(Get-Process $ListboxListeServers.SelectedItem))
    $dgvInstalledRolesFeatures.DataSource = $null
    $dgvInstalledRolesFeatures.DataSource = $processlist
})
$CommonForm.Controls.Add($ButtonShowRolesFeatures)

$CommonForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: I`ve not seen that way of defining form controls before, cuts out a lot of repetitive use of the button name variable. Thanks for that. Should make building a new WinForm quicker for hand coders.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thank you! It is what needed! And working!

Comment: How to make it so that when requesting new data, a new row is added, and not the current one is replaced?

Comment: @CatcherRem im glad it was helpful. See update reg. updating the Grid. Essentially, set the `DataSource` to null then reassign the ArrayList to it